# How to tap a square and draw "Cross (X)" on tic-tac-toe for iibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am having much difficulty trying to figure out how to draw the cross in the square of where the person just touched.

I have made a class called 'CellPositions', by making 9 invisible squares around my board Texture; Example of CellOne...

```
public CellOne cellOne;

public CellPositions(Board board) {
    load(board);
}

public void load (Board board) {
    cellOne = new CellOne(board);

}

public class CellOne {
    public Rectangle square = new Rectangle();

    public CellOne (Board board) {

        square.x = board.boardRect.x;
        square.y = (board.boardRect.y + board.boardRect.height) - (board.boardRect.height / 3);
        square.width = board.boardRect.width / 3;
        square.height = board.boardRect.height / 3;
    }
}
```

I have made a 'Controller' class to handle my input and a 'Renderer' class to handle rendering images to the game.

[image: Here is an image of my atlas]

What I want to do is draw the "Cross" on the square the person touched. For eg. if he/she touches the first square - cellOne - how would i render my "cross" to that specific square.

I've tried making a class called "Cross" and made the x and y coordinates Gdx.input.getX() and Gdx.input.getY(), but the 'cross' was not in the square, but intersecting the lines.

Please help! I am trying to get used to libGdx by making a simple game like tic-tac-toe, but it's really not so simple when trying to draw your cross on a certain square.

Here is my board class for further info

```
private TextureRegion reg;
public Rectangle boardRect;

public Board () {
    init();
}

private void init () {
    reg = Assets.instance.board.boardRegion;
    boardRect = new Rectangle();
    boardRect.set((Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (340 / 2), 15, 
            340, 340);

}

public void render (SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(reg, boardRect.x, boardRect.y, 
            boardRect.width, boardRect.height);
}
```

I have made my screen width and height be 480x480.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a multiple-step solution for you:

1. Change your cell classes to be more generic. You currently have one class for each cell position (I assume from your code). You should just have one `Cell` class that you re-use for every cell.

   ```
   public class Cell {
       public Rectangle square;

       public Cell (float x, float y, float width, float height) {
           square = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set the position of the cell when you create it (probably in your `init()` method of your board class).

   ```
   float width = boardRect.width / 3f;
   float height = boardRect.height / 3f;

   for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
       for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
           // Create new cell att appropriate position and
           // add it to a list of all 9 cells.
           // You might need to offset the x & y position by your boards
           // position as well. In that case just do: 
           // x * width + boardRect.x
           // y * height + boardRect.y
           cells.add(new Cell(x * width, y * height, width, height);
       }
   }
   ```
3. When you click you search thorough all cells and see which one you clicked in.

   ```
   int mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
   int mouseY = Gdx.input.getY();

   for(Cell cell : cells) {
       if(cell.square.contains(mouseX, mouseY) {
           // We pressed in this tile. Draw image here and size
           // it to be the same size and in the same position
           // as the cell.
           float x = cell.square.x;
           float y = cell.square.y;
           float width = cell.square.width;
           float height = cell.square.height;
           // Draw image at (x, y) with size (width, height).
           // If you're using sprites do this:
           crossImage.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
           // If you're using textures do this:
           batch.draw(crossImage, x, y, width, height);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(alternative to my first answer)</sub>

You can round the clicked position to get which cell you clicked in.

```
int mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
int mouseY = Gdx.input.getY();

// Move coordinates so we are relative to origin (0, 0).
// This makes calculations easier.
mouseX -= boardRect.x;
mouseY -= boardRect.y;

// Divide x and y by cell width and height.
mouseX /= (boardRect.width / 3);
mouseY /= (boardRect.height / 3);

// Check if you clicked outside the board.
if(mouseX > 2 || mouseY > 2) {
    // You clicked outside of the board. Do something.
}

// mouseX & mouseY is now in the range [0, 2].
// Multiply by cell width and height again.
mouseX *= (boardRect.width / 3);
mouseY *= (boardRect.height / 3);

// Move coordinates back so they match with the board position.
mouseX += boardRect.x;
mouseY += boardRect.y;

// mouseX & mouseY should now be in the correct position.
batch.draw(crossImage, mouseX, mouseY, boardRect.width / 3, boardRect.height / 3);
```

This might be a little confusing but this works because of integer division rounding (see [this short wolfram alpha explaination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)). Basically after integer division the decimals (if they are present) are truncated. So for example `5 / 2 = 2.5` but since it is integer division decimals get removed so the result is `2`.